# Docker entrypoint not working as expected

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Docker container that executes a bash script as its `ENTRYPOINT`. This script does lots of things that rely on environment variables being configured.

The strangest thing happens, when I run the container, the entrypoint script is executed, and for a lack of better words, it eventually fails.

Now, if I enter the container manually `$ docker exec -it <id> bash` Then manually run the SAME script, it works!

What's going on here? Why does Docker executing the script differ from myself manually executing the script?

UPDATE for more context

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM cuda:torch:cudnn # Not real source, but these are what are in play

# setup lua and python

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.py"]
CMD ["start"]
```

**entrypoint.py**

```
class DoSomething:

    def methods_that_work(self):
        ...    

    def run_torch(self):
        """
        I do NOT work if called from the Dockerfiles ENTRYPOINT
        I DO work if I manually run ./entrypoint.py start from within the container
        cmd = ['th', ...]
        subprocess.run(cmd)
```

Torch and Lua need to know where CUDA and CudNN are located. I can confirm all the ENV vars are set. When run via the Docker ENTRYPOINT, torch just kinda hangs, no errors, no anything, just kinda hangs.

When I bash into the container and manually run ./entrypoint.py it works.

Comment: Can you please add your DockerFile ?

Comment: I can not because of the proprietary nature of what's going on. But I can share the entrypoint. `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]` It should be noted, this script works, it runs maybe 60% of the code, but then fails, eventually because it's not getting env variables. Though, I can see they are all set. If I enter the container and run that manually, it works.

Comment: What is your WORKDIR as you are running from `./` ? I mean your in right directory ?

Comment: WORKDIR is correct. Its set to the directory of the entrypoint.sh. The same place I can execute it from. The only difference is executing the script via docker run or from within the container itself. Its mind boggling.

Comment: What permission you have given to script ?I have similar use case and it works for me. Can't figure it out what's the problem is ..

Comment: root permissions

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] without any proprietary code?

Comment: Yes. Will update main post.

Comment: You're using the exec form of entrypoint which does not do shell processing and thus your environment variables aren't substituted. If you use the shell form of entrypoint, or you explicitly invoke a shell it should work: `ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.py start` or `ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","./entrypoint.py", "start"]`

Comment: I tried the latter with bash but it didn’t work. I’ll keep playing around with it. Thanks, I’ll let you know if I can get it working that way.

Comment: The example provided is not complete or verifiable. I'm unable to reproduce your issue here.

Comment: Its impossible to share a complete example without giving the proprietary code. The long and short. Is I think @DazWilkin is on to something. However, using the Shell version of an ENTRYPOINT still doesn't have an effect. Next I'm going to try using CMD instead. This is running in AWS ECS so maybe ECS is doing something funny.

Comment: Alas, changing the entrypoint to use a shell _does not work_. Same results.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into this situation. This was explicitly an issue with Lua.

Lua paths expect to be delineated with `;` not `:` like `$PATH` for example.

`$LUA_PATH=/some/path;/some/other/path`

Now, for why this was working in an interactive bash shell, and not via Docker? Well inside the `.bashrc` there was an "activate torch" function that essentially did a find and replace on `:` to `;`.

The end of the day, this was not a Docker issue, but simply incorrectly formatted Lua environment variables.